# Remove auto generated comments in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

The comment in particular I'm having beef with is added when I tab complete the name of a method I'm overriding. Phpstorm helpfully adds // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub. I know. That's what I'm working on. For simple methods, it's worse to have to remove the comment than to just type out the declaration. Is there a setting somewhere to turn that off?

I'm using 2019.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the setting for PHP Override method body in the code tab of
"File and Code Templates" settings:

[image]